# How can we access variables and functions on console even if the script has been executed way before?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

We know that when our whole JS program is executed it's GEC (Global Execution Context) is popped out of the call stack. And since GEC stores the global scoped variables and function, so all those memory is also released.

Then how even after executing the whole .js file, then too we are able to access those variables and function on any browser's console ?

Comment: The first paragraph in the question is incorrect. No memory is released from the global scope, everything stored in it is live for the lifetime of the browsing context.

Answer (score 0):

After execution of the js files, all globally scoped variables are stored on the browser's memory. you can access them by their name directly or you can access the global variable by the global object of variables named "window".
like:
console.log(window.varname);

Comment: what about closure then ? Are they also stored in the browser's memory ?

Comment: That is also stored in the browser's memory. But, it might lead to memory leaks if the closure reference is not managed properly in your code. Try to release references to closures that are no longer needed. thank you.